# Ansible docker_container: wordpress->mysql No route to host

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, ansible

I wanted to create a dockerized app with ansible, worpdress and mysql. So i used a playbook with de docker_container module:

in vars:

```
dockers:
  mysql:
    volume: mysql-data
    volume_mount: /var/lib/mysql
    volume2: '{{ docker_vols }}/mysql-cnf/my.cnf'
    volume_mount2: '/etc/mysql/my.cnf'
    image: mysql:latest
    name: mysql
    restart: always
    #ports: "3306:3306"
    mem: "512M"
  wordpress:
    volume: wp-content
    volume_mount: '/var/www/html/wp-content'
    volume2: wp-data
    volume_mount2: '/var/www/html/'  
    image: wordpress:latest
    name: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports: "8080:80"
    mem: "512M"
```

the task:

```
    ---
    - name: setup mysql
      docker_container:
        name: "{{ dockers.mysql.name }}"
        image: "{{ dockers.mysql.image }}"
        volumes:
          - "{{ dockers.mysql.volume }}:{{ dockers.mysql.volume_mount }}"
        state: started
        restart: yes
        restart_policy: "{{ dockers.mysql.restart }}"
        memory: "{{ dockers.mysql.mem }}"
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "{{ MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }}"
          MYSQL_DATABASE: "{{ MYSQL_DATABASE }}"
          MYSQL_USER: "{{ MYSQL_USER }}"
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: "{{ MYSQL_PASSWORD }}"
      tags: [ 'docker-run' ]
    
    - name: setup wordpress
      docker_container:
        name: "{{ dockers.wordpress.name }}"
        image: "{{ dockers.wordpress.image }}"
        volumes:
          - "{{ dockers.wordpress.volume2 }}:{{ dockers.wordpress.volume_mount2 }}"
          - "{{ dockers.wordpress.volume }}:{{ dockers.wordpress.volume_mount }}"      
        state: started
        restart: yes
        restart_policy: "{{ dockers.wordpress.restart }}"
        memory: "{{ dockers.wordpress.mem }}"
        ports:
         - "{{ dockers.wordpress.ports }}"
        links:
          - "mysql:mysql"
        env:
          #WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "{{ WORDPRESS_DB_HOST | default(omit) }}"  #also tried: "mysql:3306"
          WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "{{ WORDPRESS_DB_USER }}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "{{ WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD }}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "{{ WORDPRESS_DB_NAME }}"
      tags: [ 'docker-run' ]
```

But in the logs in the wordpress docker says:

```
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No route to host
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I assume that the error is in the links part, but tried all forms i found and still can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Using link is a legacy feature of docker [link](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/). You can rather create a docker network and connect the both container in same network so that they can talk each other.

```
    - name: "Create a network"
      docker_network:
        name: "{{ docker_network_name }}"
```

add these line to every container.

```
        networks:
            - name: {{ docker_network_name }}
```

And your setup should be like

```
---
    - name: setup mysql
      docker_container:
        name: "{{ dockers.mysql.name }}"
        image: "{{ dockers.mysql.image }}"
        volumes:
          - "{{ dockers.mysql.volume }}:{{ dockers.mysql.volume_mount }}"
        state: started
        restart: yes
        restart_policy: "{{ dockers.mysql.restart }}"
        memory: "{{ dockers.mysql.mem }}"
        networks:
            - name: {{ docker_network_name }}
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "{{ MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }}"
          MYSQL_DATABASE: "{{ MYSQL_DATABASE }}"
          MYSQL_USER: "{{ MYSQL_USER }}"
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: "{{ MYSQL_PASSWORD }}"
      tags: [ 'docker-run' ]
    
    - name: setup wordpress
      docker_container:
        name: "{{ dockers.wordpress.name }}"
        image: "{{ dockers.wordpress.image }}"
        volumes:
          - "{{ dockers.wordpress.volume2 }}:{{ dockers.wordpress.volume_mount2 }}"
          - "{{ dockers.wordpress.volume }}:{{ dockers.wordpress.volume_mount }}"      
        state: started
        restart: yes
        restart_policy: "{{ dockers.wordpress.restart }}"
        memory: "{{ dockers.wordpress.mem }}"
        ports:
         - "{{ dockers.wordpress.ports }}"
      
        networks:
           - name: {{ docker_network_name }}
        env:
          #WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "{{ WORDPRESS_DB_HOST | default(omit) }}"  #also tried: "mysql:3306"
          WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "{{ WORDPRESS_DB_USER }}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "{{ WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD }}"
          WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "{{ WORDPRESS_DB_NAME }}"
      tags: [ 'docker-run' ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see that "link" usage it's deprecated, didn't know that. I'm gonna test it out and see the results.

Comment: Still the same. As i can see with the `docker network ls` and the `docker network inspect bridge` it already create a bridged network and joins both dockers on in. Even put the hostname resolution and ip address in the _/etc/hosts_ file. Must be something else... SELinux? i'm gonna check that